# How do I find a constant in an oscillation as given by a sphere in motion?

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> The acceleration of an oscillating sphere is defined by the equation
>   $a=-ks$. Find the value of $k$ such as $v=10\,\frac{cm}{s}$ when $s=0$
>   and $s=5$ when $v=0$.

The given alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&15\\
2.&20\\
3.&10\\
4.&4\\
5.&6\\
\end{array}$

What I attempted to do here is to use integration to find the value of $k$.

Since the acceleration measures the rate of change between the speed and time then:

I'm assuming that they are using a weird notation *"s"* for the time.

$\dfrac{d(v(s))}{ds}=-ks$

$v(s)=-k\frac{s^2}{2}+c$

Using the given condition: $v(0)=10$

$10=c$

$v(s)=-k\frac{s^2}{2}+10$

Then it mentions: $v(5)=0$

$0=-k\frac{25}{2}+10$

From this it can be obtained:

$k=\frac{20}{25}=\frac{4}{5}$

However this value doesn't appear within the alternatives. What part did I missunderstood?. Can somebody help me here?.

Comment: What is $s$? From the context mentioning oscillation, could it be displacement?

Answer (score 1):

The term oscillating is very generic, so this could be a pendulum for example. I'm assuming $s$ stands for the position of the sphere. Then, notice that $$a =\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{dv}{ds}v$$
Therefore, we have $$\int v dv = -\int ks ds \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}{v}^{2}= -\frac{1}{2}ks^{2}+C$$
Now, if $s=0$ we have $v=10$ (I'm ignoring units) so $C = 50$. Now, if $s = 5$, $v = 0$ and this implies $k=4$.

Comment: I am confused. Why did you used $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$ and not just $\dfrac{dv}{ds}$ why did you had to put those together and not just one as i did. What is the justification of this? The procedure that you used is it the chain rule? As you mentioned the $s$ also confused me. If is the position the does this means that I had to assemble the differentials in such a way that can be integrated in the other side of the equality?

Comment: I also wonder. Could this problem had been solved using the equations for harmonic oscillators? If so how? I intended to imply this in my question. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell it is basically the harmonic oscillator. The point here is: when you consider $s$ to be the position of the sphere, $s$ itself can be a function of time, so you have to find a way to relate only $v$ and $s$ without explicit dependence of $t$. This is why I used the chain rule to express $v$ as a function of $s$, in a sense. Remember that $a$ is the derivative of $v$ w.r.t $t$ not $s$.

Comment: I don't know what you meant by w.r.t Does it mean *with respect of time*?. If so then this makes sense. I just don't know why on earth did this question was posed this way when it could had been easily been stated for $t$ and not $s$. Will your trick also work wiht partial derivatives?.

Comment: Yes, it means with respect to. There is a nice way to understand the trick.You know, by Newtons second law, that $F = m a = m dv/dt = m d^{2}x/dt^{2}$. Now, if we are dealing with forces that have some dependence on $t$ or $x$, you have to solve a differential equation to find the equations of the motion. If $F$ depends on $t$, the ODE is easy solved, but in the case $F$ depends on the position $x$, you have to write the right side of Newton's equation in terms of $x$. That's where the trick takes place!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize is that $s$ is *not* a "weird notation for time". It's a fairly standard notation for distance along a path.
It is used much the same way as $x$ is used in other problems, except that we tend to use $x$ when we know the motion is in a straight line and can declare that line to be the $x$ axis, whereas not every oscillation problem involves straight-line motion.

So $v = \frac{ds}{dt}$ and $a = \frac{dv}{dt}.$

Then you might recognize $a = -ks$ as an example of Hooke's Law and you might recall that the result is sinusoidal oscillation around $s = 0.$
But you don't actually need to know that.

All you really need to know is that along the path of length $5$ units from $s = 0$ to $s = 5,$ the velocity of the sphere is reduced from $v = 10$ to $v = 0.$
If you let the letter $m$ stand for the mass of the sphere, 
then the force $F = ma = -mks$ acts on the sphere along that path.
You can integrate over $s$ to figure out how much work that force does on the sphere
and match that to the change in kinetic energy of the sphere.
The change is negative, because we go from whatever kinetic energy the sphere has at $v = 10$ (I hope you remember the formula for that) to zero at $v = 0$.

Comment: I do remember what you refer when you mention that the change in kinetic energy is the mechanical work. But I don't recall exactly what formula are you referring to. Could it be $W=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$?.

Comment: That's one of the Hooke's Law formulas. There are some things that don't quite match the problem in question; your formula is for a force $-kx$, but they used $s$ instead of $x$ and their formula gives acceleration rather than force. But acceleration vs. force is just a matter of a factor of $m$ for mass.